# Как запустить асинхронную программу и программу на PyQt5 кореектно?

Tags: python, pyqt5, многопоточность, asyncio, threading

Есть 2 программы, первая построена на блокирующих функциях опроса различных устройств через последовательные порты, общается с базой данных и иногда шлет информацию на сервер. Так как много блокирующих операций была написана с применением библиотеки asyncio. Вторая программа, выводит различные сообщения и заставки на экран, была написана на PyQt5.

Пример запуска программ:

```py
def start_qt_widgs():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = MainWindow()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


th = threading.Thread(target=start_qt_widgs,) #запуск программы на PyQt5 
th.start()
    
asyncio.run(main()) #запус асинхронной программы
```

Когда происходит запуск, программы работают корректно, но я получаю предупреждение -
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
Как я понимаю, это связанно с запуском приложения написанном PyQt5 в отдельном потоке, а его нужно запускать в родительском.
Вопрос, какие проблемы могут возникнуть? И как можно реализовать передачу данных между двумя этими программами, если запускать их на одном компьютере? В текущей реализации программы общаются через очереди.

Comment: А нужен ли вообще отдельный поток, если уже удалось победить блокирующие вызовы асинхронным кодом?

Comment: На сколько я знаю PyQt5 не поддерживает асинхронность. Есть библиотеки asyncq, но они под более старые версии питона и тогда всю программу на pyqt придется переписывать.

Comment: https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync - вполне живой проект

Comment: qt  сам по себе асинхронный - можно чисто на нем с компортами общаться

Comment: он асинхронный, но необходимо опрашивать 2 последовательных порта, базу данных и как клиент слать информацию на сервер. Придется прибегать к QThread, чего не хотелось бы делать.

Comment: я бы несколько подпроцессов запустил.